# Full authentication is required to access this resource when trying to get authentication token for REST service

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I need oauth2 for my personal project, so I'm going through [this](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) tutorial on Spring web-site.

My configuration mostly is taken from their [example project](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-bookmarks), security module.

However when I launch the app, I cannot obtain a token. The server keeps showing "Full authentication is required to access this resource" when I try to make a POST request to http://localhost:8080/oauth/token.

I'm using Postman for creating a request. Used Import to convert this:

```
curl -X POST -vu android-bookmarks:123456 http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=password&username=defaultuser&grant_type=password&scope=write&client_secret=123456&client_id=android-gps_tracker_server"
```

I've spent some time searching for an answer, but all the cases I found didn't work for me. What could be the problem?

Here's the configuration code:
The WebSecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter{
    final private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfiguration(PlayerRepository playerRepository) {
        this.playerRepository = playerRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return (username) -> playerRepository.findByUserName(username)//@formatter:off
             .map(a -> new User(a.getUserName(), a.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER", "write")))
             .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("could not find the user '" + username + "'"));//@formatter:on
    }
}
```

The OAuth2 Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Configuration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    private final String applicationName = "gps_tracker_server";        
    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    public OAuth2Configuration(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager(){
            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                return authenticationManager.getOrBuild().authenticate(authentication);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory()
               .withClient("android-" + applicationName)
               .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token")
               .authorities("ROLE_USER")
               .scopes("write")
               .resourceIds(applicationName)
               .secret("123456");
    }
```

And the main app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GpsTrackerServerApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GpsTrackerServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter(@Value("${tagit.origin:http://localhost:9000}") String origin) {
        return new FilterRegistrationBean(new Filter(){
            public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
                String method = request.getMethod();

                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,OPTIONS,DELETE");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", Long.toString(60 * 60));
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization");
                if ("OPTIONS".equals(method)) {
                    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
                } else {
                    chain.doFilter(req, res);
                }
            }

            public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) { }

            public void destroy() { }
        });
    }
```

}

There are also two YML files, one application-https.yml and another application.yml. The latter only holds DB cridentials and "profiles.active: https". The first one looks like this:

```
server:
    port: 8443
    ssl:
        key-store: classpath:tomcat.keystore
        key-store-password: defaultuser
        key-password: defaultuser
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. I had to place client_id and client_secret into Postman's 'Username' and 'Password' fields of 'Authorization' tab, with option 'Basic Auth' enabled. Then I was able to get an access token.
When using import from Curl statement, Postman placed id and secret into x-www-form-urlencoded body, which was not working.